# Test if a Time field value changed in flow decision... causing exception

Tags: visual-workflow, bug, time

I ran into an issue with a flow who stopped with an error, giving no more details than :

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this
> ErrorId if you contact support: 2033648372-927914 (81955499).

The log showed no error at all, just endend after a decision.
I could isolate and reproduce the issue:

- I created a SObject Test__c with a field named TimeField__c, and an instance of it, and then created a flow with this decision:

[image: Flow decision Time changed]

Then I debugged the flow, not even changing the time, and I got this error : *Value of class com.force.swag.soap.Time is not a ValueType: STRING*

[image: Error in flow]

It's obviously a Salesforce bug, I should be able to check if a time field changed.
Using `Record.Timefield__c != Record_Prior.Timefield__c` or using a formula to compare values didn't help, the bug's still here.

I found however a workaround that I'll share in an answer.

Comment: I fell into the same trap: [Time is not supported by Flows](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/371675/time-to-text-conversion-in-flows).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I created a formula (text type) to reference the time field, simply `TEXT(TimeField__c)`
[image: Formula Time field]

and then updated my decision to reference the formula instead of the Time field.

[image: Record>FormulaTimeField IsChanged True]

The bug is no longer active and the comparison works since it's not directly on a time field anymore.